# R Plotly adding multiple line chart with dropdown menu

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
    date       food    transp  housing  other
0   2015-06-01  1510    45.58   0       101.5
1   2015-07-01  1163.91 74.14   210     106.7
2   2015-08-01  101.3   95.03   210     54.5
3   2015-09-01  1131.67 22.28   210     46.3
4   2015-10-01  818.44  88.88   815.2   47.2
```

I am aiming for chart "Olympic medal" in the link [chart](https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/), it is implemented in plolty via python and I am trying to replicate in R. What I have been able to do is [this](https://plot.ly/~Biranjan/3/button-restyle/#plot)
In first glace it looks similar but I don't have the drop down menu 'All' which contain all the lines. At present there is no way to bring back the plot with all the lines unlike in the first chart where there is option 'All'. Code below shows how I created my second plot. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
plot <- plot_ly(newf, x = ~round_date, y = ~other, name='other', type='scatter',mode='lines+markers') %>%
add_trace(y = ~food, name = 'food') %>%
add_trace(y = ~housing, name = 'housing') %>%
add_trace(y = ~transport, name = 'transport') %>%
    layout(
title = "Button Restyle",
xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
yaxis = list(title = "y"),
updatemenus = list(
    list(
    type = "buttons",
  y = 0.8,
  label = 'Category',
  buttons = list(
    list(method = "restyle",
         args = list("y",list(~other)),
          label = "houshold"),

   list(method = "restyle",
         args = list("y",list(~food)),
          label = "communication"),

   list(method = "restyle",
         args = list("y",list(~housing)),
          label = "food"),

   list(method = "restyle",
         args = list("y",list(~transport)),
          label = "transport")

            ))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the y-values it is preferable to hide/show axes. You can hide and show axes in plotly by passing an array to the visible attribute, e.g. `args = list('visible', c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))` would show the first axis and hide the other two.

See below for the full code or [here](https://plot.ly/~MaxPeters/293/mpg-power-qsec/) online.

Changing from a scatter plot to a bar chart would screw up the restyle process when the y-values are changed, you would get 4 bars with different colors but identical y-values.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(mtcars, x = rownames(mtcars), y = ~mpg, name='mpg', type='scatter', mode='markers') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~hp, name = 'power', type='scatter', mode='markers') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~qsec, name = 'qsec', type='scatter', mode='markers') %>%
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = "buttons",
        x = -0.1,
        y = 0.6,
        label = 'Category',
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list('visible', c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)),
               label = "View all"),
          list(method = "restyle",
             args = list('visible', c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
             label = "Hide all")
        )
      ), 
      list(
        type = "buttons",
        x = -0.1,
        y = 0.7,
        label = 'Category',
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list('visible', c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
               label = "mpg"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list('visible', c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "hp"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list('visible', c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
               label = "qsec")
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just didn't know I could hide and show axes.